# create data driven angular form

Tags: angularjs, html, forms

I have a project that needs to create a form with the title of each text field comes from a json from another server.
I need to use ng-repeat to show the title and use ng-model for the text field itself, but how do I return all the result back to the server in a json format?

Here is my html part

```
 <div class="row" ng-controller="createworkshopController">
                <form role="form" ng-submit="submitWorkshop()">
                        <div>
                            <div ng-repeat="x in form">
                                <h4>{{x.field_name}}</h4>
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="{{x.field_name}}" ng-model="result.form[field_name]">
                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <hr>

                        <div align="right">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="submitWorkshop()">Submit</button>
                            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset</button>
                        </div>
                </form>
 </div>
```

And here is what I have for angular controller

```
app.controller('createworkshopController', function($scope, $http) {

$http.get(end_url + ':' + port + '/createworkshop')
    .success(function(data) {
        $scope.form = data.Workshop;
    });


$scope.submitWorkshop = function() {

};
```

});

Here is a picture of what the html look like right now, The form title is passed in easily.
[image]

Please help me! I'm still learning! Thanks!!!

Comment: Add `name="myform"` attribute and you will be able to access it in controller via `$scope.myform` in submit handler. Then construct the object and use `$http` to send

Comment: did you handle this there are a lot of example on web?

Comment: Doesn't $scope.result.form contain all of the changed information you need?

Comment: yes but how do I return it back as json in $scope.submitWorkshop?

Comment: Is there a way for me to test of the form result is being passed in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$http({ method: 'POST', data: $scope.result.form, url: 'path/to/api' })

This will send JSON data of the $scope.result.form object to the required API URL.

Comment: So I should put this inside the $scope.submitWorkshop? so that when I press submit, this will be executed? Also, what kind of json format will I get in return?

Comment: Yes. You will get `{ field-name: value, field-name: value .... }`. Use the dev tools to debug your network request.

Comment: Thank You! Let me try it

Comment: Hi sorry to bother you! but when I debug it, I get that the $scope.result.form is undefined?

Comment: Your model is `ng-model="result.form[field_name]"`. Are you sure it shouldn't be x.field_name?

Comment: I tried x.field_name but everything just go haywire. Like the placeholder all become x.field_name. also how should I link it to the controller?

Comment: Can you upload your code or a sample of it to a plunker? It is hard to understand where your problem is.

Comment: I can see your problem. Inside your ng-repeat you need to be using `x in form.Workshop` as this is the array you are iterating over. Also make sure to inject $http into your controller.

Comment: I figured out! the ng-model should be something like result[x.field_name] and in angular controller there should be an empty $scope.result={};